# Changing language of a JComboBox

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization

So I'm writing a program where I have to change the language to a different language I have that part done but I can't seem to get the JComboBox to change language so for example if the user clicks Japanese the languages in the JComboBox change from English to Eigo and French to Furansugo is there a piece of code that would specifically do this and does it go in with the ActionPerformed that I have for the languages?

You probably don't need it but here's my code:

```
    /**
     * 
     */
    package gui;

    import javax.swing.*;

    import gui.GUI;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    /**
     * @author Michelle
     * 
     */
    public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        ResourceBundle res, res1, res2;
        JFrame frame;
        JButton button, button1, button2, button3, button4;
        JLabel label, label1,label2,label3, label4;
        JScrollPane output;
        JComboBox<String> combo;
        String[] array;

        public GUI()
        {           
        Locale loc = new Locale("fr"); //create Locale for French in France

        res = res.getBundle("programResource.ProgramResource_fr",loc); //Create resource bundle
        res1 = res1.getBundle("programResource.ProgramResource_jp",loc);
        res2 = res2.getBundle("programResource.ProgramResource_en",loc);

            Container c = getContentPane();
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            String[] array = {"English", "French", "Japanese"};
            combo = new JComboBox<String>(array);
            output = new JScrollPane(combo);
            combo.addActionListener(this);

            JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();

            mb.add(output);

            setJMenuBar(mb);

            label = new JLabel();
            label1 = new JLabel();
            label2= new JLabel();
            label3 = new JLabel();
            label4 = new JLabel();

            ImageIcon apple = new ImageIcon("apple.jpg");
            label.setIcon(apple);
            button = new JButton("Apple");
            button.addActionListener(this);

            ImageIcon banana = new ImageIcon("banana.jpg");
            label1.setIcon(banana);
            button1 = new JButton("banana");
            button1.addActionListener(this);

            ImageIcon grapes = new ImageIcon("grapes.jpg");
            label2.setIcon(grapes);
            button2 = new JButton("Grapes");
            button2.addActionListener(this);

            ImageIcon orange = new ImageIcon("orange.jpg");
            label3.setIcon(orange);
            button3 = new JButton("Orange");
            button3.addActionListener(this);

            ImageIcon pear = new ImageIcon("pear.jpg");
            label4.setIcon(pear);
            button4 = new JButton("Pear");
            button4.addActionListener(this);

            p.add(label);
            p.add(label1);
            p.add(label2);
            p.add(label3);
            p.add(label4);
            p.add(button);
            p.add(button1);
            p.add(button2);
            p.add(button3);
            p.add(button4);
            c.add(p);

            setSize(425,300);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        //French
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            Button(a);
            Button1(a);
            Button2(a);
            Button3(a);
            Button4(a);

            }

    public void Button(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JComboBox ref = (JComboBox)a.getSource();

            if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("French"))
            {
                button.setText(res.getString("computeButton"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("Japanese"))
            {
                button.setText(res1.getString("computeButton1_jp"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("English"))
            {
                button.setText(res2.getString("computeButton_en"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Button1(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JComboBox ref = (JComboBox)a.getSource();

            if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("French"))
            {
                button1.setText(res.getString("computeButton1"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("Japanese"))
            {
                button1.setText(res1.getString("computeButton1_jp"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("English"))
            {
                button1.setText(res2.getString("computeButton1_en"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Button2(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JComboBox ref = (JComboBox)a.getSource();

            if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("French"))
            {
                button2.setText(res.getString("computeButton2"));
            }

            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("Japanese"))
            {
                button2.setText(res1.getString("computeButton2_jp"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("English"))
            {
                button2.setText(res2.getString("computeButton2_en"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Button3(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JComboBox ref = (JComboBox)a.getSource();

            if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("French"))
            {
                button3.setText(res.getString("computeButton3"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("Japanese"))
            {
                button3.setText(res1.getString("computeButton3_jp"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("English"))
            {
                button3.setText(res2.getString("computeButton3_en"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Button4(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JComboBox ref = (JComboBox)a.getSource();

            if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("French"))
            {
                button4.setText(res.getString("computeButton4"));
            }

            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("Japanese"))
            {
                button4.setText(res1.getString("computeButton4_jp"));
            }
            else if(ref.getSelectedItem().equals("English"))
            {
                button4.setText(res2.getString("computeButton4_en"));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [tutorial on how to use ResourceBundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html)? If not, please have a look at it as it can help you to organize your code.

Comment: I don't need to organise my code I have 4 other classes for the ResourceBundles I understand what is happening I need to figure how to change the language for the JComboBox and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this example defining your listener properly would certainly help.
I also don't understand why you have 3 instances of bundles... you should have 1 according to the desired language..

```
    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.setCaption(ResourceBundle.getBundle("yourfile",your_locale).getLabel("fruit.banana"));
    button1.setIcon(CommonIcons.ADD);
    button1.addListener(new ClickListener()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7855693595481663167L;

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            handleAddButton();
        }
    });
```

I think you should be ok with that. I would also suggest you make an array of jpgs and an array of JButton... and initialize them in a loop. this way you would manage n objects and not duplicate the code which is messy...

Comment: Okay I understand where you're coming from but I don't need suggestions on how to tidy my code up and I need to make 3 different languages that's why I have 3 instances of bundles all I want to know is how to make the language in my JComboBox change and that's it